# Кодировка URL при отправке get запроса

Tags: c#, api, get

Всем привет!

Сегодня столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Я формирую URL для GET запроса и отправляю GET запрос. URL генерируется правильно, но отправляется, как я понял, не правильно. Я задебажил получаемый URL, он был правильный, но после того, как я вставил в адресную строку браузера из такого запроса: `http://localhost:61513/zertixapi/api/auth&admin&adminloh123@123sq`
запрос превращается в такой:
`http://localhost:61513/zertixapi/api/auth&admin%E2%80%8B&adminloh123@123sq%E2%80%8B` и соответственно сервер выдаёт неправильный результат

Сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с таким и как это фиксить?

Вот код, как я отправляю запрос:

```
            string sURL;
            sURL =  base_url + "auth&" + _login.text.Replace(" ", "") + "&" + _pass.text.Replace(" ", "");

            WebRequest wrGETURL;
            wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(sURL);

            WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy("myproxy", 80);
            myProxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = true;

            wrGETURL.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();

            Stream objStream;
            objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objStream);

            string sLine = "";
            int i = 0;

            while (sLine != null)
            {
                i++;
                sLine = objReader.ReadLine();
            }
```

**P.S**
С прямой ссылкой работает

**РЕШЕНИЕ:**

У меня был установлен TextMeshPro (TMP), и из него я брал текст, и видимо каким-то магическим образом, он добавлял свои знаки. Вообщем установил Text и всё норм)

Comment: @Andrew я читал эту статью, в запросе у меня нет ни "запрещённых" символов, ни пробелов

Comment: Я вроде говорил вам про `HttpClient`, а вы все равно эту древность `WebRequest` используете, которая вешает вам приложение на время выполнения запроса. Цитата [отсюда](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?view=netframework-4.8): _Важно! Не рекомендуется использовать `WebRequest` или производные классы для новой разработки. Вместо этого используйте [`System.Net.Http.HttpClient`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) класс._ Если уж меня не услышали, так может документация для вас имеет значение.

Comment: Еще вот это почитайте обязательно, потому что вы плодите ошибки: [Использование объектов, реализующих `IDisposable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects)

Comment: @aepot не бей))

Comment: Перед первым параметром должен присутствовать знак вопроса `?`!!! Иначе вся строка будет приниматься как просто `path`. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL

Comment: Вот, да `base_url + "auth?"`

Comment: @mik.ov, спасибо! Я второй день в этой сфере, ещё изучаю. Получается надо так?```[HttpGet("api/auth?{login}&{pass}")]```

Comment: Посмотрите в документации, как реализуются GET методы. `[HttpGet("api/auth")] public ... Auth(string login, string pass) { ... }`. Но передача пароля в GET запросе, это вообще не прикольно. Используйте POST. И вообще поищите примеры, как другие люди делают авторизацию. Велосипедов понаписано уже очень много сортов.

Comment: @aepot спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для генерации урла:

```
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
var paramValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);

paramValues.Add("param1", "value1");
paramValues.Add("param2", "value2");
uriBuilder.Query = paramValues.ToString();

//твой результат
var urlWithParams = uriBuilder.Uri;
```

для доставания из урла значения параметра:

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://www.example.com?param1=good&param2=bad");
string param1 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("param1");
```

оба кода найдены по запросу "c# url set with parameters"

Comment: всеровно появляются такие знаки

Comment: знаки могут появлятся, главное что бы появлялись правильные знаки как было в таблице по ссылке.

Comment: знаков вообще нет, там онли англиские буквы

Comment: если вставляются "лишние" знаки - значит ты их передаешь. По-другому быть не может. Например они могут быть невидимыми символами. Или символами отсутствующими в твоем шрифте.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259275/removing-hidden-characters-from-within-strings

Comment: где же я их вставляю https://disk.yandex.ru/i/dchvWosk_O9I-Q

Comment: их выводит дебаг-логгер юнити вероятнее всего. Поставь брейкпоинт, а потом вытяни значение напрямую из переменной.

Comment: не, в любом случае, URL который я отправляю, он правильный

Comment: я не добавляю никаких знаков и тд